# Given set of points in 2d space, each with some penalty, find a convex region covering exactly N points, minimizing penalty

Tags: algorithm, geometry, convex-hull, approximation

Is there an algorithm for this?  It's okay if it's an approximation or adds further constraints to simplify.  Here's a more detailed statement

I have K points in some low dimensional space (say 2d).  Each one has a penalty (could be zero).  And if it helps, we could restrict it so that there are only a few discrete penalty values rather than a continuum.

Given N, I want to find a convex region that contains exactly N of these points.  The cost of a region is the sum of the penalties of all the points.  We want to minimize this cost.

e.g., you must find a convex region of land with exactly N trees.  Some trees are worse (higher penalty) than others, so you want to find the optimal such region.

Is there a known algorithm for this?  It's okay if the solution is only approximately optimal.  It would also be okay to only cover approximately N, but I don't want to relax this too much.  Or, it would be okay to introduce some simplifying constraints, such as:  the convex region must be a triangle (can only be defined by 3 points).

I suppose with the triangle constraint, I could do a brute force search on a random sample of the input points search of all possible triangles defined by 3 points, but this would be something like O(S^4) where S is my sample size.  S^3 triangles and O(S) loop over points to check if they're in that triangle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If n is not too large you could try integer programming. Enumerate all n choose 4 combinations of 4 points, filter out the combinations that don't have one point `x1` inside the triangle formed by the other three `x2, x3, x4`, write a constraint

```
-x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 <= 2
```

for each combination, plus a cardinality constraint

```
sum_i x_i = n
```

and minimize

```
sum_i penalty_i x_i.
```